# flutter_slidable has no isOpen field?

Tags: flutter

I have a requirement that when my `flutter_slidable` is open, tapping on it closes it, rather than executing my onTap callback.

I'm not seeing an `isOpen` field to check whether the slidable is open. I have a workaround where I check to see how long it took to close after an onTap. If it closes fast, I assume it was already closed.

Is there a "real" way? Here's my workaround

```
const int closingTimeMS = 500;
final stopwatch = Stopwatch();
stopwatch.start();
await slidable.close(duration: const Duration(milliseconds: closingTimeMS));
if (stopwatch.elapsedMilliseconds < closingTimeMS / 2) {
    myOnTap();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Calling this in an `onTap`/`onPressed` solved it for me

```
final isClosed = Slidable.of(context)!.actionPaneType.value == ActionPaneType.none;

if (isClosed) {
  Slidable.of(context)!.openStartActionPane();
} else {
  Slidable.of(context)!.close();
}
```